# Getting HTTP xml error response using cURL

Tags: c++, http, networking, curl, libcurl

I am currently using cURL to communicate to a cloud site... everything is going well except for an annoying issue. The issue is that I cannot get the site's xml response when there is an error. for example, when I use Wire Shark to check the transfer I can see that in the HTTP header that I'm getting which contains the error code; there is an XML data that contains in addition to the error code, a message that describes the code. I have tried many cURL options to try and get the XML but all my attempts failed.

Could someone tell me how can I get the XML. please note that I'm using the cURL C APIs as my code is in c++ and moreover, I can get XML responses when the operation succeeds using my write callback function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set CURLOPT_FAILONERROR to 0.  If this is set to 1, then any HTTP response >= 300 will result in an error rather than processing like you want.

Comment: thanx man I'm not sure why I've set it to 1 in the first place although this created a new problem since cURL now returns CURL_OK even if there was an error so I guess its time for serious xml parsing :)